# how to return multiple values from a function and use that in somewhere else in python programme

Tags: python, function, return-value

How can I return two values from a function?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried :)

Comment: def addHost()  
   defaults={ip addresses}  
   h=cls(name,**defaults}
   return h,defaults

>I want to access h and defaults in other part of the python programme.How can I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

functions can only return a single value.

It's easy to pack multiple values into a tuple and return that

```
def f(x, y):
    retval1 = x + y
    retval2 = x * y
    return retval1, retval2
```

You can unpack the returned tuple like this

```
sumval, prodval = f(5,7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you cannot return two values/objects from a function. The concept which comes into picture here is -> `tuple packing` and `tuple unpacking`.

```
def foo():
    return 'one','two'


a,b = foo()
```

What you are doing here is, while returning the values from a function, you are using a single tuple object and your comma seperated values (here string `'one'` and `'two'`) are packed into the tuple and you are returning that tuple containing objects. (by using this concepts you can return as many object as you want). This is `tuple packing`.

And while calling your function, you are retrieving these tuple values by associating the variable names (here `a` and `b`) to it, this is called `tuple unpacking`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo():
    return 'foo','bar'

>> print foo()[0]
'foo'
>> print foo()[1]
'bar'
```

The function returns a tuple of the return values, so you can access them just as you would a normal tuple

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

```
def a(): return 1, 2

def b(): return (1, 2)

def c(): return [1, 2]

def d(): return { 'value1': 1, 'value2': 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A function can return a tuple, which can contain values. This allows you to return more than one value from a function.

For example, two values in a function:

```
def blah():
    a = 1
    b = 2
```

From there one can create a tuple containing these two values and return it:

```
return (a,b)
```

This will return a tuple, which you can assign to variables:

```
name1 = a
name2 = b
```

In your case, perhaps you want to do this:

```
return (h, defaults)
```